# Retaining Older Uploaded Image In Db

Tags: php, html, image-uploading

I have a page in my clients dashboard for editing his about content.

Once i click on edit button it redirects to another page and there is an option for uploading new image and also content.

Problem :If no new image is uploaded suppose only some text fields are changed and clicked on update the text content changes and redirects to main page but image is deleted from db,but i don't want image to be deleted from the db if no new picture is uploaded.

Two Files Are there
1)index.php 
2)editabout.php

index.php

```
<div class="main-container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">
                <?php include('db.php'); $select=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `about`"); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)){?>
                <div class="col-md-3"><img id="profileimage" src="about/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" style="width:100%;height:200px;" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" required>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6"> <a href="editaboutimg.php?bid=<?php echo $row['sl.no']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Edit this image?');"><input style="width:100%;" class="btn btn-info btn-lg mb-3 mr-3" type="submit" value="Edit"></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php}?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

editabout.php

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="main-container file-upload">
    <div class="file-upload__dropzone">
    <?php
    include('db.php');
    $select=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `about` where `sl.no`='$bid' ");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)){
    ?>
    <img id="profileimage" src="about/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" style="width:100%;height:200px;">
    <?php } ?>

      <div class="file-upload__browse-files">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg btn-block btn-rounded file-upload__browse-btn">Browse files</button>
        <input id="upload-files-default" name="img" type="file" multiple class="upload" onchange="readURL(this);">
      </div><br>
     <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg mb-2 mr-3" name="ok" type="submit">Update</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Php code for uploading

```html
include('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['ok']))
{
$photo=$_FILES['img']['name'];  
$target_dir = "about/"; 
$location = $target_dir .$_FILES["img"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],$location);
$query1="UPDATE `about` SET `image`='$photo',
        `up_date`=now()
         WHERE `about`.`sl.no` ='$bid'";
mysql_query($query1);
```

Comment: No code, No help

Comment: looks like you are replacing the old image with the new (empty) image.. you will need to check IF an image has been uploaded and otherwise dont delete the old one!

Comment: i have added code used check and tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check does the file exist/uploaded or not before executing any query. As an example below:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"] && file_exists($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"])){
   //update query with picture
   //move_uploaded_file here
}else{
  //Only query updating does details without move_uploaded_file
}
```

Above code must be put in the `if(isset($_POST["ok"]))` code block.

Comment: will try this and let you know